# What's the best way to select last element of a parent element that has a child of some type?

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent

I'd like to select last element of a parent Z that has a child element Y of some type in pure CSS?

As in: http://jsfiddle.net/c26rt/6/

I'd like to be able to select the gray square regardless of the number div.x's I might have in pure CSS.

So given:

```
<div class="z">
    <div class="x"><div class="y"></div></div>
    <div class="x"><div class="y"></div></div>
    <div class="x"><div class="y"></div></div>  
    <div class="x"><div class="y"></div></div>
    <div class="x"><div class="y"></div></div>
    <div class="x"><div class="y"></div>selected</div>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="x"></div>
</div>
```

I want the background-color of the last div.y above be gray.

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS, so it's not possible to select elements depending on it's content. You have to use JavaScript to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [there is no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), you won't be able to do this with pure CSS. Even if you gave all the `.x` elements that have `.y` children an additional class name, you would still be unable to select the last among those elements, because there is no last-of-class selector.

You'd have to programmatically find the last `.x` containing a `.y` to add an extra class name for you to select in CSS.

Comment: Even if it were possible to use the level 4 subject selector (described in the link and **as yet unimplemented**) to match the element you're looking for, e.g. `:nth-last-match(1 of .x! > .y) > .y`, the fast CSS profile doesn't allow either the subject selector or `:nth-last-match()` to be used this way anyway, so you'd still have to rely on JavaScript even once it's implemented.